# Spring Security <http> and <intercept-url> pattern attributes

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have seen Spring Security OAuth2 samples has this defined in the `spring-servlet.xml`,

```
   <http pattern="/users/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/photos" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/photos/trusted/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT,SCOPE_TRUST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/photos/user/**" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_TRUST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/photos/**" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

Is the `pattern` attribute in `http` tag valid? I could not find its definition in the `spring-security-2.0.1.xsd`. If it is valid, what is the relationship of this pattern with `intercept-url`'s `pattern` attribute? Take for example, does the intercept path `/photos/user/**` has the final matching interception path of `/users/photos/user/**`? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute was introduced in [3.1](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd) which introduced namespace support for multiple filter chains. Spring Security 2 is very out of date (you shouldn't be using it).

The patterns in the `intercept-url` elements are independent, in that they are matched against the incoming request URI in the same way as the filter chain `http` pattern is checked. However if the latter doesn't match, the filter chain won't be applied to the request at all, so in order to have any effect, they must be consistent with the filter chain pattern.

For the example you've posted, this would mean that none of the `/photos` patterns have any effect. They should all have the prefix that the main filter chain matches - i.e. they should begin with `/users/photos`.

Comment: Is there anywhere mentioned why the configuration is designed like that? I mean it is not intuitive and make the whole <http> configuration useless and go unnoticed as in my example.

Comment: How else would you design it other than having the two be independent? Deciding whether one ant pattern is "contained" within another isn't an easy problem. What if the filter chain pattern was `/**/users/**` for example?

Comment: On top of my head, we could have a fail fast path collision between <http> patterns e.g. /user/** will collide with /user/photos where it should be declared as <interrupt-url> inside /user/** <http> pattern. Tough patterns like /**/users/** are outlawed where you could have either /**/users or /users/**. I have to look at some difficult patterns to determine of what I say holds.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of spring security 4, Role is checked by haseRole('ADMIN'), Just try it.

It works fine for me.

Comment: this doesn't look like an answer to me... please make it a comment